# Yii dropDownList nested conditions (not nested dropDown)

Tags: yii, nested, conditional-statements

in a dropdown I would like to find data in 2 levels. Maybe my logic is wrong, but as I remember I have done such things before, the only difference was that I got always 1 simple result back, but now, I should handle an array. Here's my code:

```
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'szeriaGyartmanyId', GxHtml::listDataEx(
        SzeriaGyartmany::model()->findAllAttributes(
            null, true, 'rajz_osszetett_technologia_id IN (:rajz_osszetett_technologia_id) AND keszDb<db', array(
                ':rajz_osszetett_technologia_id' => RajzOsszetettTechnologia::model()->findAllAttributes(
                    null, true, 'osszetett_technologia_id = :osszetett_technologia_id', array(
                        ':osszetett_technologia_id' => OsszetettTechnologia::model()->find("name='Horganyzás alatt'")->id
                    )
                )->id
            )
        )
    ), array('style' => 'width: auto', 'prompt' => ''));
```

the core gives back one single ID, it's no problem, but the second level gives back an array (or array of objects? I'm not sure). The point is, is it possible here somehow to implode resulting rajz_osszetett_technologia_ids, or do I have to do completely differently? I've tried to implode it right in place, but I got an error: Argument must be an array. So that's why I guess the result is an array of objects.

Is it clear what I would like to achieve? For me it seems kinda obvious to do it somehow like this, but maybe my logic is completely wrong. Can somebody please point me to the right direction?
Thanks a lot!
BR
c

Comment: Is this what you try to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/dUcVT/

Comment: no, I would like to find in the first step an ID of a technology in the Technology table. That's working. Second step, I would like to find all ID's in the corresponding table, regarding technologyId, and provide it like so (kinda imploded): (id1, id2, id3...), and in the last step, to find data in the 3rd table regarding imploded ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GxActiveRecord::findAllAttributes(null,true..)` returns an array of objects with only the required properties set. In order to obtain an array of ids as required you need to wrap it in `GxHtml::listDataEx()` and then use `array_keys` to obtain only the keys.

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'szeriaGyartmanyId', GxHtml::listDataEx(
    ....
    ':rajz_osszetett_technologia_id' => implode(',',
        array_keys(
            GxHtml::listDataEx(
                RajzOsszetettTechnologia::model()->findAllAttributes(
                ....
                )
            )
        )
    )
    ....
)
```

Perhaps a custom query would be easier and clearer than this.

Comment: works almost great, thank you so much, but the interesting thing is, that the query results 2 rows, and I can only see 1 row in the dropdown. Why can it be?

Comment: Is it the outer or inner query that has 2 rows?

Comment: it's maybe not related to the solution.